# SSH connection with python from a device (not computer)

Tags: python

I'm using a Digi 3G router that can be programmed with python, and I want it to make periodic SSH connections to another device. I've read everything about paramiko, but don't know how to install it in the router.
I want to know if there is any other way of including paramiko into a device, apart from installing (i.e. including some library), or if it exist another possibility apart from paramiko for this particular case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The description for the Digi 3G states that it is capable of python scripting, using a custom development environment.  To make this work, you would have to use the python source code from paramiko; the executable would not be installable directly on the router (since the executable is designed to be run on a computer, not a router).

The source code would probably have to be  modified, since the APIs for this sort of thing are most likely different than those in a computer, and the router would have to be capable of what you are asking of it.

Comment: Ok, but then: what can I do?
Is it absolutely necesary to install paramiko (or any other thing) in the router?
Can't I do it just with the support of a normal file, such as a library?
Is there any other SIMPLE way of making a ssh conecction without paramiko?